# Display on the sidebar data that has certain value in database

Tags: php, laravel

I want to display the specialities that I have only is their value in the same table in the database is equal to 1, and not display when it is equal 0. I tried making if statements but they return errors. Any idea how can I get the value from the database and check it?

```html
@foreach($specialties as $key => $specialty)

    {{--@if ($value->{$key::is_template} = 1)--}}
    @if(value("{{$key->is_template}}") === 1)

    <li class="pcoded-hasmenu pcoded-trigger" dropdown-icon="style3" subitem-icon="style7">
        <a href="#">
            <span class="pcoded-micon"><i class="ti-calendar"></i><b>M</b></span>
            <span class="pcoded-mtext">{{$key}}</span>
            <span class="pcoded-mcaret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="pcoded-submenu">
            @foreach($specialty as $training)
            <li class=" ">
                <a href="{{route('practitionerView', $training->training_id)}}">
                    <span class="pcoded-micon"><i class="ti-angle-right"></i></span>
                    <span class="pcoded-mtext">{{$training->name}}</span>
                    <span class="pcoded-mcaret"></span>
                </a>
            </li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </li>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: Dunno why you use quotes here, but `@if($key->is_template === 1)
` is enought

Comment: please show us the  $specialties array structure

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `$specialties` is an array/Collection like this:

```
$specialties = [
    'a' => new Specialty(['is_template' => 1]),
    'b' => new Specialty(['is_template' => 0]),
    'c' => new Specialty(['is_template' => 1]),
];
```

A condition `@if ($specialty->is_template === 1)` or `@if ($specialty->is_template)` would work.

Alternatively, if you want to save a few lines, you could replace the foreach with `@foreach($specialties->where('is_template', 1) as $key => $specialty)`(this works on a Collection but not a regular array)